# Pointer to existing object?

Tags: objective-c

Ok so I have a class that I init like so in `QuickNoteNotesDataController.m`

```
QuickNoteNotesDataController *dataController = [[QuickNoteNotesDataController alloc] init];
```

Then I need to be able to access the same instance of this class from another file `QuickNoteDetailViewController.m`

How do I get a pointer to the same instance without calling alloc init again and creating a new instance?

Comment: Someone implemented my answer to code, and you accepted it? you should have asked me for code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with a singleton if you only need one instance:

```
//In QuickNoteNotesDataController.m
static QuickNoteNotesDataController *sharedInstance;
+ (id)sharedDataController {
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[QuickNoteNotesDataController alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Otherwise you could create a property in the `QuickNoteDetailViewController`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) QuickNoteNotesDataController *dataController
```

and set the dataController you already have to the property when you create the detailViewController.

Comment: That is right, but probably to advanced for this question. On the other hand, who tells us that only one instance is needed in total?

Comment: @totalitarian, less advanced but probably not strictly following the OO dogma, would be to introduce a property within your second view controller and set it from external. A bit more objective-c like could be to hand the pointer over in a custom init method and not a setter. However, this would sort of bind the two classes wich is not always advisable. A singleton is a good idea when you really need exaclty one instance of this object through the full run time of your App. Still a singleton but less advanced would be not to use dispatch_one or the block command. Hoever, it works for you. Fine

Answer (score 1):

Same instance from other class : you need to create a shared instance.

Or a static property for this.

But do not go with `extern variable`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your QuickNoteNotesDataController class as Singleton,by then you can share single instance of this class in whole app.